# NSTableView column Header text editing not working properly

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want to change the table view column header text on double clicking column header.
For that I created a subclass of NSTableHeaderCell like-

```
@interface NBETableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell<NSTextFieldDelegate,NSTableViewDelegate>
@end

#import "NBETableHeaderCell.h"
@implementation NBETableHeaderCell

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTextView *editor = notification.object;
    [self setTitle:editor.string];
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
    [self endEditing:editor];
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    if([self isHighlighted])
    {
        [self drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView.superview];
    }

    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}

- (void)drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [controlView lockFocus];
    NSSetFocusRingStyle(NSFocusRingOnly);
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cellFrame] fill];
    [controlView unlockFocus];
}
@end
```

I set the table column header cell class

```
-(void)setupTableHeader:(id)table {
    NSArray *columns = [table tableColumns];
    NSEnumerator *cols = [columns objectEnumerator];
    NSTableColumn *col = nil;

    NBETableHeaderCell *iHeaderCell;

    while (col = [cols nextObject]) {
        iHeaderCell = [[NBETableHeaderCell alloc] initTextCell:[[col headerCell] stringValue]];
        [col setHeaderCell:iHeaderCell];
        [[col headerCell] setEditable:YES];
        [iHeaderCell release];
    }
    [table setTarget:self];
    [table setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickInTableView:)];
}
```

The double click action I set was :

```
- (void)doubleClickInTableView:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [myTableView clickedRow];
    NSInteger column = [myTableView clickedColumn];

    if(row == -1&& column >= 0)
    {
        NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[myTableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:column];
        NSTableHeaderView *headerView = [myTableView headerView];
        NBETableHeaderCell *headerCell = [tableColumn headerCell];
        id cellEditor = [self.view.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:myTableView];
        [headerCell setHighlighted:YES];
        [headerCell selectWithFrame:[headerView headerRectOfColumn:column]
                             inView:headerView
                             editor:cellEditor
                           delegate:headerCell
                              start:0
                             length:headerCell.stringValue.length];

        [cellEditor setDrawsBackground:YES];
    }
}
```

Now, I am able to edit the column header and set a new text. On tabbing out the new text persist. But if I set a new text and instead of tabbing out I click on other table column header, my text is not changed, the old value is being retained. This may be because the delegate `- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification` is not called upon selecting other table column header. This delegate is only called on tabbing out. Please suggest, how can set the new value in the table column header cell without tabbing out?

Comment: Seems you solved this in another thread. Would you update your code?

Comment: @ctietze.. I don't remember the changes I had made... I left cocoa programming a year ago :) Will let you know if I find that changes somewhere ..